# Redirect to another page when clicking the close button in jQueryUI Dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

What I want to do is when you click the close button in a jQueryUI Dialog, the Dialog will close and the whole page will be redirected to somewhere else. How to achieve this? It seems that I should bind the close event with some extra logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#popup').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
     window.location = "http://www.mydomain.com";
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an event handler bound on the `close` event:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
    close: function () {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }
});
```

(this assumes you have a button defined somewhere that already closes the dialog)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hR2vN/